# Rational Solutions to equations like $a^2+3b^2=k^3$

Tags: diophantine-equations, normed-spaces, extension-field

I'm working on the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, and I want to find elements $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ such that the polynomial $X^3-\frac{\overline{\alpha}}{\alpha^2}$ be irreducible.
In other words I need $\frac{\overline{\alpha}}{\alpha^2}$ to be a cube, but:
$$\frac{\overline{\alpha}}{\alpha^2}=\frac{\overline{\alpha}^3}{N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)}$$
And thus, we just need the norm $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)$ to be a cube. If $\alpha=a+b\sqrt{3}$, then the norm is equal $a^2+3b^2$. So I want to find solutions to equations:

$$a^2+3b^2=k^3, \ a,b,k \in \mathbb{Q}$$

Does this kind of equation have a way to find solutions of it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is necessary to solve the equation  $c(a^2+3b^2)=k^3 $ ?

Comment: Since $N(\alpha^3) = N(\alpha)^3$, any $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ provides a solution in the form of $\alpha^3$.

Comment: Yes, I need to find infinite of such $\alpha$.